# Select shapes based on defined names and generate hyperlinks to specific rows

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, shapes

I have a macro that inserts a shape with a defined name in cell A2, in adjacent cells to the shape (Cell C2 and C4) the macro also inserts the defined name of the inserted shape and a number that represents a row number on sheet 2.

The shape will later be moved to another place in the same sheet so it won't stay in Cell A2. I will also be adding more shapes with the macro above.

What I need is to make every shape that gets inserted into a hyperlink that takes the user to the right row on sheet 2 in the same workbook.

So I need to write code that selects the shape whose name is in cell C2 and then makes that into a hyperlink that connects to column A and to the right row whose number you can see in Cell C4

Here is the code I got from recording the macro

```
' hyperlink Makro

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("A20_Provpunkt_>Fa")).Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:=""
```

And this is an example of how I want it to work

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("**Value from Cell C2**")).Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), 
Address:=**Rownumber that you get from Cell C4**
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Better to also post the code you use to initially populate the sheet - it would be easier to modify that than to create some "add on" code you run after that's done.

Answer (score 0):

adds hyperlink on shape with subaddress to sheet 2 column A and using row value of C4

```
    Sub AddHyperlinkOnShape()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shapeName As String
    Dim shape As shape

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    shapeName = ws.Range("C2").Value
    Set shape = ws.Shapes(shapeName)

    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shape, Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="'Sheet2'!A" & ws.Range("C4").Value, _
        ScreenTip:="This is the way"
End Sub
```